# How to properly center UITabBar items vertically for UITabBar with larger height and no item titles?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I'm working on a custom UITabBar that has a larger height, custom shadow and no item titles.

I am using the following code for my custom UITabBar class to achieve this like:

```
class CustomUITabBar: UITabBar {

    @IBInspectable private var height: CGFloat = .zero

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else {
            return super.sizeThatFits(size)
        }
        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            sizeThatFits.height = height + window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            sizeThatFits.height = height
        }
        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```

Here is the result: On iPhones that have notch (iPhone X, XS, 11, etc.) it looks fine, icons are centered properly, like so:

[image]

But on iPhones that have home button instead, tab bar items are not propery centered vertically. Is there a solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now they are not centered as I see it on both devices. You can play around with this code:

```
guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
                
                for item in items {
                    item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                }
```

it adjusts image of TabBarItem:)

With this settings they are going to be centered in each TabBarItem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that code did not change anything :(